# Android Facebook like post on my page as the current user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a like to a picture\post in a page I manage.

I didn't request the manage_pages permissions, since I don't want to manage the page.

I'm trying to post a like action to one of the pictures in my page thorough the Android Facebook SDK, but it says that a manage_pages permissions is required.

When i'm giving that permission, the like is being posted as the Page.

Can I somehow tell the SDK to post it by the user and not by the page the user owns ?

Answer (score 0):

In the API call, instead of the `page access token`, use the `user access token` to post as the user with `publish_actions` permission

Comment: I use the Session that Facebook generated in the login flow. And i didnt ask for manage_pages so why would I have the page's access token?